# How can I check if concatenated date is correct using Datetime.TryParse?

Tags: c#, linq

I've created a date value using year, month, and day. I've concatenated it into a string.

```
commPaymentDay = (x.BrokerCommissionStatement.PaymentYear + "-" + x.BrokerCommissionStatement.PaymentMonth + "-" + x.BrokerCommissionStatement.PaymentDay)
```

I want to use DateTime.TryParse to convert the string into a DateTime and check if if it's a valid date.

```
 success = String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Key.commPaymentDay) ? false :  DateTime.TryParse(p.Key.commPaymentDay, out dateTime),
```

If it is a valid date I want to assign it to a property of DateTime.

```
PaymentDay = dateTime
```

The problem is that PaymentDay is always coming back with a null value "0001-01-01"

Complete Method:

```
public async Task<List<BrokerCommission>> FetchAsync(Broker broker)
{

  DateTime dateTime;

  var comm = await _myContext.DocScan
    .Include(x => x.BrokerCommissionStatement)
    .Where(x => x.BrokerId == broker.BrokerId && x.Type == FileType.BrokerStatement
    && x.BrokerCommissionStatement.PaymentYear == x.ScanDate.AddMonths(-1).Year
    && x.BrokerCommissionStatement.PaymentMonth == x.ScanDate.AddMonths(-1).Month)
    .Select(x => new { x.FileGuid, x.FileUrl, x.ScanDate, commission = (x.BrokerCommissionStatement.Amount + x.BrokerCommissionStatement.Vat), commPaymentDay = (x.BrokerCommissionStatement.PaymentYear + "-" + x.BrokerCommissionStatement.PaymentMonth + "-" + x.BrokerCommissionStatement.PaymentDay) })
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.FileGuid, x.FileUrl, x.ScanDate, x.commPaymentDay })
    .Select(p => new BrokerCommission
    {
      FileGuid = p.Key.FileGuid,
      FileUrl = p.Key.FileUrl,
      ScanDate = p.Key.ScanDate,
      Commission = p.Sum(x => x.commission),
      success = DateTime.TryParse(p.Key.commPaymentDay, out dateTime),
      PaymentDay = dateTime
    })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.ScanDate).Take(10)
    .ToListAsync();
}
```

I've declared the property **success** as a boolean

Comment: What is the content of "p.Key.commPaymentDay"? Can you post it in here? It would rly help.

Comment: @HirasawaYui "p.key.commPaymentDay"  is an anonymous type which returns the concatenated date string. I'm getting the values from my database.

Comment: `success = String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Key.commPaymentDay) ? false :  DateTime.TryParse(p.Key.commPaymentDay, out dateTime)` can be simplified to `success = DateTime.TryParse(p.Key.commPaymentDay, out dateTime)` because `DateTime.TryParse(null, out dateTime);` doesn't throw an exception, but returns `false`

Comment: Is `success` true or false after processing ?

Comment: @mjwills `success` is a boolean property, it isn't given a value....  Not sure where you're getting 1st Feb 2019 from?

Comment: @Cid value of `success` is true, but getting empty default date "0001-01-01".

Comment: If you change the code to `.Select(p => { var hello = DateTime.TryParse(p.Key.commPaymentDay, out dateTime); return new BrokerCommission
    {
      FileGuid = p.Key.FileGuid,
      FileUrl = p.Key.FileUrl,
      ScanDate = p.Key.ScanDate,
      Commission = p.Sum(x => x.commission),
      success = hello,
      PaymentDay = dateTime
    };})` does it work?

Comment: @mjwills that was my thought too, separating the `TryParse` from direct initialization.

Comment: If my suggestion doesn't work, please move `dateTime` to be **declared** on the line **after** `hello`. This will ensure it isn't a variable scoping issue.

Comment: @mjwills apologies for the late response, I've been in a meeting..... Tried your suggestion and got:  `a lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree`. Should I do this in the select to BrokerCommission object?

Comment: @mjwills They are not stored as strings, the dates are stored as year(smallint), month(tinyint), day(tinyint). I'm trying to build a single date and parse it as a DateTime.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are failing to check the boolean return value from `DateTime.TryParse`.

If `TryParse` returns false, then the string could not be interpreted as a valid `DateTime`, so the `out` parameter will hold a meaningless empty default as you have described.

Comment: even with the value of `success` being true, I still get the default value "0001-01-01"

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use [DateTime.TryParseExact()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.8) where you can supply the datetime format you use.

A simple example:

```
var dateTimeString = new DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTimeString, "dd-MM-yyyy", out parsedValue) == true)
{
    // parsedValue is a DateTime variable that holds the parsed value of the datetime string
}
else
{
    // dateTimeString is not in the desired format
}
```

**Update**

Your code would look like this:

```
public async Task<List<BrokerCommission>> FetchAsync(Broker broker)
{

  DateTime dateTime;

  var comm = await _myContext.DocScan
    .Include(x => x.BrokerCommissionStatement)
    .Where(x => x.BrokerId == broker.BrokerId && x.Type == FileType.BrokerStatement
    && x.BrokerCommissionStatement.PaymentYear == x.ScanDate.AddMonths(-1).Year
    && x.BrokerCommissionStatement.PaymentMonth == x.ScanDate.AddMonths(-1).Month)
    .Select(x => new { x.FileGuid, x.FileUrl, x.ScanDate, commission = (x.BrokerCommissionStatement.Amount + x.BrokerCommissionStatement.Vat), commPaymentDay = (x.BrokerCommissionStatement.PaymentYear + "-" + x.BrokerCommissionStatement.PaymentMonth + "-" + x.BrokerCommissionStatement.PaymentDay) })
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.FileGuid, x.FileUrl, x.ScanDate, x.commPaymentDay })
    .Select(p => new BrokerCommission
    {
      FileGuid = p.Key.FileGuid,
      FileUrl = p.Key.FileUrl,
      ScanDate = p.Key.ScanDate,
      Commission = p.Sum(x => x.commission),
      DateTime.TryParseExact(p.Key.commPaymentDay, "yyyy-MM-dd", out dateTime),
      PaymentDay = dateTime
    })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.ScanDate).Take(10)
    .ToListAsync();
}
```

In my version it doesn't collect the result of `TryParseExact`, because I don't really know how you would use it. If you are **100% certain** of the datetime format and that the object you parse **always** contains a valid value, it will always succeed and this code will parse the datetime.

Comment: I'm getting the date values from the db, so where would I supply the date format?
Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm just really lost.

Comment: Above is just a common example. You can use `TryParseExact()` instead of `TryParse()`. Most likely the problem you are facing is that the format of the datetime string you are parsing is not in the "default" format. The TryParse then fails and it returns a useless value. If you use `TryParseExact` where you now use `TryParse` you can supply the format for your datetime string and it will parse it, returning the correct value

Comment: So currently when I run the code I do get a value for `success` and I get a value for `commPaymentDay`, the problem is assigning the value of `Datetime` to `PaymentDay`... I do get the correct date value in "yyyy-MM-dd" format....
please refer to code in question above.